# CKEditor: How to place text when mouse is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I hope this is simple. I have a case where I want to insert an HTML element in a document when the mouse is clicked in a specific place in the document.  Specifically, an HTML anchor tag, e.g:

```
<a name="whatever"></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Insert text into ckeditor textarea or when  ckeditor generated anchor clicked insert text into dom?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic click event handler that allows you to position the anchor element absolute wherever you click.

Super easy to do without a framework.

```js
    function addAnchor(ev){
    
      var anchor = document.createElement('anchor');
      anchor.innerHTML = "This is the anchor element";
      anchor.style.position = 'absolute';
      anchor.style.left = ev.clientX + 'px'
      anchor.style.top = ev.clientY + 'px'
      anchor.className += 'whatever';
      document.getElementById('document').appendChild(anchor);
    }
    
    document.querySelector('#document').addEventListener('click', addAnchor)
```

```css
#document{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.whatever{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
    <div id="document">
      <a class="whatever">click anywhere</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: OP asks for help with CKEditor, not with a regular page. You will have to use the CKEditor api to add the text where the cursor is.

Comment: True... I appreciate the code to insert the anchor that way, but the key is dealing with CKEditor.  It's docs are pretty awful, IMO.

Comment: I would just use native javascript to do it

Comment: All you have to do is position the anchor tag absolute and then get the clientX and clientY properties from the click event. Then subtract that from the offset x and y for the document div. Then you just style the anchor tag with the values in left and top. Would you like me to change the snippet for you?